# Ajax post method not updating the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Trying to pass an attribute value to PHP through an jQuery post method. It is successful according to the console.log but the page is not refreshing the $_POST value on the page. However, it shows in the data on success.

jQuery post data:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dracanon Application</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>Array
(
    [id] => 22
)
data from ajax post:22<br/><form name="test" method="post" action="">
<div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#newaltrequest">New Requests</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#archive">Archive</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="newaltrequest" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>New Requests</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped" id="application-table">
                <div class="display-limit">
                    <div class="btn-group page-limit">
                        <button id="pagelimit" type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span>10</span><span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <input type="hidden" id="limit-selection" name="limit-selection" />
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu limit-selector" role="menu" >
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="5">5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="10">10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="25">25</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="50">50</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="All">All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <script>
                            $('.limit-selector li a').click(function (e) {
                                var value = $(this).data("value");
                                $('#limit-selection').val(value);
                                document.getElementById("classForm").submit();
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-container">
                    <script>
                        /* limit page dropdown */
                        $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){
                            $('.dropdown-toggle').html('<span>'+$(this).html() + '</span><span class="caret"></span>');
                        });
                        /* End  limit page dropdown */
                    </script>
                </div>                
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Alt Character</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>bwilson</td><td>Bracchius</td><td class='btnreview'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-small reviewbutton' data-toggle='modal' 
                           data-target='#view_detail_modal' 
                           data-requestid='22'>Review</button></td></tr><tr><td>dcaldessa</td><td>sojurne</td><td class='btnreview'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-small reviewbutton' data-toggle='modal' 
                           data-target='#view_detail_modal' 
                           data-requestid='23'>Review</button></td>
                    </tr>
               <!--<script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $(document).on('click','.reviewbutton',function () {
                                var requestid = $(this).attr('data-requestid');
                                console.log(window.location);
                                $.ajax({
                                            type:"POST",
                                            url: "../index.php",
                                            data: {id: 13},
                                            success: function (data) {
                                    console.log("data-resolved");
                                }
                                        });
                                    });
                        });
                    </script>-->                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="archive" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Archive</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped" id="archive-table">
                <div class="display-limit">
                    <div class="btn-group page-limit">
                        <button id="pagelimit" type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span>10</span><span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <input type="hidden" id="limit-selection" name="limit-selection" />
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu limit-selector" role="menu" >
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="5">5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="10">10</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="25">25</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="50">50</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="All">All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <script>
                            $('.limit-selector li a').click(function (e) {
                                var value = $(this).data("value");
                                $('#limit-selection').val(value);
                                document.getElementById("classForm").submit();
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-container">

                    <script>
                        /* limit page dropdown */
                        $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){
                            $('.dropdown-toggle').html('<span>'+$(this).html() + '</span><span class="caret"></span>');
                        });
                        /* End  limit page dropdown */
                    </script>
                </div>                
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Alt Character</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>Sample Data</td>
                    <td>Sample Data</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).on('click','.reviewbutton',function () {
            var requestid = $(this).attr('data-requestid');
            var value = {id: requestid};
            console.log(window.location);
            $.post("testing.php",value, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

so it shows that the data is being returned but it is not refreshing the $_POST array to display the values on the screen.

Below is the original form:

```
<?php
include "includes/header.php";
include "includes/functions.php";
print_r($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    print_r("data from ajax post:".$_POST['id']."<br/>");
}else if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    echo "data not found";
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['requestlimit'])) {
    $_SESSION['requestlimit'] = 10;
}else if (isset($_POST['limit-selection'])){
    if($_POST['limit-selection'] != null) {
        $_SESSION['requestlimit'] = $_POST['limit-selection'];
    }
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['archivelimit'])) {
    $_SESSION['archivelimit'] = 10;
}else if (isset($_POST['limit-selection'])){
    if($_POST['limit-selection'] != null) {
        $_SESSION['archivelimit'] = $_POST['limit-selection'];
    }
}

$start=0;
$limit=$_SESSION['archivelimit'];

if(isset($_GET['pid']))
{
    $id = $_GET['pid'];
    $start = ($id-1)*$limit;
}
else
{
    $id=1;
}

?>
<form name="test" method="post" action="">
<div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#newaltrequest">New Requests</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#archive">Archive</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="newaltrequest" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>New Requests</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped" id="application-table">
                <?php include "includes/pagelimit_button.php"?>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Alt Character</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php include "includes/alt_requestlist.php"?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </thead>
                <?php /*include "includes/view_alt_request.php" */?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="archive" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Archive</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped" id="archive-table">
                <?php include "includes/pagelimit_button.php"?>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Alt Character</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sample Data</td>
                        <td>Sample Data</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click','.reviewbutton',function () {
            var requestid = $(this).attr('data-requestid');
            var value = {id: requestid};
            console.log(window.location);
            $.post("testing.php",value, function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could I get some suggestions or assistance in the right direction to resolving this issue?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: The AJAX response is *not going to refresh* the `$_POST` array. You need to take the values from the AJAX response and use JS/jQuery to update the fields.

Comment: `print_r("data from ajax post:".$_POST['id']."<br/>");` PRINT_R() prints arrays and not scalar strings, are you getting a crash or at least an error message in error log, use echo

Comment: have you cleaned cache ?

Comment: I have tried using echo and get nothing back, I have also cleared the cache of firefox with no luck, I have used console.log with firefox and it passes the value of the id via jquery with a success message of the success operation in ajax so it is getting through at some point but seems to be getting lost somewhere on displaying it.

Comment: I have tried using echo and get nothing back, I have also cleared the cache of firefox with no luck, I have used console.log with firefox and it passes the value of the id via jquery with a success message of the success operation. in the first part of my post I have the results of the ajax response and it is displaying the ID but the page itself is not  displaying anything. There are no errors on the page or in the log.

Answer (score -1):

The $_POST variable is evaluated at the serer side when you request the page. When you do the AJAX request, the $_POST variable is evaluated in a separate page, which returned values will be evaluated on the browser side in the success method. The $_POST variable will therefor not be updated, but you should use javascript or jQuery to process the returned value and place them in your page at the positions of where the values of the $_POST variable are.